# Vuforia in BT-2000 in Android Studio

Tags: android, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I'm developing an AR app fro Epson Moverio BT-2000.

During this phase of the project I want to make use of the vuforia libraries (https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk). In this first phase, in order to know more about the vuforia library I've installed some samples. This samples run in other android platforms, namely in my cellphone and there is also one sample developed for augmented reality glasses, namely for Moverio BT-200.

However, when I Install the apk in Moverio BT-2000 there is an error saying: "Failed to initialize Vuforia. This device is not supported"

I did not found any useful information about this error on the internet. So, I really would like to know how to solve this situation or if there is any way to make vuforia compatible with Moverio BT-2000?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: The Epson BT-2000 is not a device currently supported by Vuforia 6.

For the complete list of supported devices, please review the following: http://www.vuforia.com/Devices

Comment: @Jayshree So there is no way to use the vuforia lib on Moverio BT-2000? Do you any suggestion which libs are compatible with Moverio BT-2000? if not i can only use opencv as an hardcore way to developed an augmented reality app?

Comment: @Ricardo. You could use ARTookit. You only need to change the default video size.